# Is it possible to duplicate a Redis Sorted Set?

Tags: redis

I'm working with two sorted sets in Redis. At a certain point i need to expire `set 1`, rename `set 2` to `set 1`. This removes `set 2`. I then need to duplicate `set 1` to recreate `set 2` as a replica. Is this possible?

I've spotted [zunionstore](http://redis.io/commands/zunionstore) in the Redis documentation but i'm not sure it's what i'm after.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Indeed, `zunionstore` seems to work fine. It does a union between the specified sets, and stores the result. If you only supply one set, it will make a copy. At least, I just tried it out and it seems to work:

```
zadd foo 1 a
zadd foo 2 b
zunionstore bar 1 foo
zrange bar 0 -1
1) "a"
2) "b"
```

Comment: Great, thanks Linus. I am doing this with the Redis Ruby gem and it appears the syntax is slightly different to what i was expecting. I ended up getting this to work in IRB with: `REDIS.zunionstore('bar', [1, 'foo'])`. Your answer is exactly the confirmation i was after though.

Comment: Awesome! I learned something new too, I'll keep this in mind!

Comment: Isn't there a more efficient way to copy? `zunionstore` is  `O(N)+O(M log(M))` according to the docs.